# Where on Earth is csc.exe?

Tags: c#, csc

After reading through a few tutorials and other questions I've had no luck in getting anything called `csc.exe` on my computer. I tried installing MonoDevelop, Mono, the .NET SDK, none of which installed `csc.exe`. Where is it? Do I need Visual C# 2008 Express or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`.

Of course, the path will be different for different framework versions.

Comment: Ah okay, wonder why I couldn't find it before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Dare you to raise a "not an answer" flag :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's **C#** **c**ompiler's acronym. It should get installed whenever a CLI-supporting development tool is installed, such as Visual Studio.